# Randomly merge two dataframes based on condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes of same length, with a shared column called `post_id`, look like this:

`df1`:

| post_id | text |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | some text 1 |
| 002 | some text 2 |
| 003 | some text 3 |
| ... | ... |
| 999 | some text 999 |

`df2`:

| post_id | text |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | different text 1 |
| 002 | different text 2 |
| 003 | different text 3 |
| ... | ... |
| 999 | different text 999 |

What I want is a new dataframe with half of the rows randomly selected from `df1`, the other half from `df2`, with all the `post_id` still in there and no duplicates. Is there a way to do this short of manually `iloc` the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is same number of columns and same index use [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) with [`DataFrame.sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html):

```
df1.update(df2.sample(frac=0.5, replace=False))
print (df1)
   post_id                text
0      1.0    different text 1
1      2.0         some text 2
2      3.0         some text 3
3    999.0  different text 999
```